# When you favourite a tweet that's been retweeted by someone you follow, will he get a notification?

Tags: twitter, favorites, retweet

1. Person X tweets a post—I don’t follow X;
2. Person Y retweets X's tweet—I follow Y;
3. I favourite the tweet that Y retweeted.

Will Y get a notification? I know it does give notification if I retweet a tweet that's been retweeted. But is it the same for favourites?

Answer (score 2):

> Will Y get a notification? I know it does give notification if I retweet a tweet that's been retweeted. But is it the same for favourites?

Yes, the person does get a notification.